# react-native: Is there a method to run iOS simulator and Android simulator at the same time?

Tags: android, react-native, ios-simulator

How to run ios and android simulator at the same time?

Now I use the ios simulator iPhone 6 and use the Genymotion to run Android.

I `cd` to my project path. I can run iOS simulator. I run Android simulator well too. Now only one simulator runs well when I run Android simulator and the iOS simulator at the same time. Then I select the iOS simulator and type command +　Ｒ，the iOS simulator run well, and then the Android simulator show red screen, the text shows me:

[image]

I select the Android simulator and reload android. Then Android simulator is running well, but the iOS simulator screen become red, the error text shows:

[image]

The bash text is this:

```
Loading dependency graph...
React packager ready.

Loading dependency graph, done.
Bundling `index.ios.js`  100.0(1274/1274), done.
Bundling `index.android.js`  100.0(1126/1126), done.
Bundling `index.android.js`  100.0(1272/1272), done.
```

I see the two simulators do not run at the same time.

Is there a method to run the two simulators at the same time?

=======

I restart the mac and run the iOS and Android simulator, now two simulators run well at the same time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simultaneously run both Android and IOS emulators with React-Native, but you can enable remote JS debugging in only one emulator at a time. If you happen to enable remote JS debugging in both emulator then one of the emulator will not work.